# condition for a cubic equation to have no roots in an interval

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, cubics

I want to find the possible values of a parameter $a$ such that the equation $2x^3-9x^2+30-a=0$ does not have a root in $(-2,2)$. I am stuck can anyone help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Have you sketched the graph of $2x^3-9x^2+30$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot $f(x)=2x^3-9x^2+30$. The critical points are the roots of $f'(x)=0$ and are easy to find.

[image]

The critical points are $x=0$ and $x=3$. We have $f(0)=30$ and $f(3)=3$. The graph shows that the equation $f(x)=a$ has a single solution for $a<3$ or $a>30$. For $a=3$ or $a=30$, the equation has two solutions (a double one). For $3 < a < 30$, the equation has three solutions. Now argue about $x \in (-2,2)$.

Comment: can u provide a detailed solution ur explanation looks correct but i am not able to think over the solution myself..... thanks for your efforts btw

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now, -22>a >30 is the solution my book seems to be incorrect it only has a<-22.Thanks a lot for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$2x^3-9x^2+20=a$$ and consider the function $$f(x)=2x^3-9x^2+30$$
$$f'(x)=6x(x-3)$$
$$f''(x)=6(2x-3)$$

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: what to do after finding critcial points i find that there is a maxima at x=0 how to proceed further??

Comment: So $f(0)=30$, what can be said about $a$ now?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the function $$f(x)=2x^3-9x^2+30-a$$ to get $$f'(x) = 6x(x-3)$$

Thus your critical points are $x=0$ and $x=3$

On the interval $-(-2, 2)$ the critical point $ (0,30-a)$ is a maximum point.

Therefore  the function f(x) does  not have any zeros in the interval $(-2,2)$  if and only if $$30-a <0$$ that is if and only if $$a>30$$

Comment: i dont know what u did wrong but the answer is a<-22

Comment: You each have half the answer. In fact the only way to have any root in $(-2,2)$ is if $-22<a\leq30.$

Comment: David K yeah now i got it ...thanks a lot